# Create view model for entity type in ASP.NET MVC just for validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

In my MVC 3.0 application, I use the database first schema of entity framework.
In the views, I want to add validation for input. Should I create a new model type for the entity that I need to validate, so that I can add validation attributes on it? Those entity types are generated by entity framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should create a buddy class with the MetadataType attribute that refers to a class with your validation. Check out this example:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

Specifically the section labeled *Using Data Annotation Validators with the Entity Framework*.

Answer (score 0):

Once you generate the EF Model classes (even with Database First Schema) you should be able to add the DataAnnotation attributes to the generated model classes.  It should be in the [ModelName].Designer.cs class file

Comment: My database schema is prone to change, it may not be appropriate to update those generated files.